# How can I check that email verification for careers site was successful?

Tags: support, email-verification

I click on the supplied link, also copy and paste it into the address bar, and it takes me to my profile, but there is no indication that anything has changed. How can I be sure the verification is successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *just* went through this process this morning and was super confused too.

If you click the link in the email, it just takes you to the careers site home page.  I presumed that meant the link wasn't correct, but...

It appears to me that the *next* time that you log in and view your profile, you'll get the standard stackoverflow style "banner" across the top that says "Thank you for verifying your email address".

So it looks like you might either have to view your profile, or maybe log out and log back in and view your profile to verify?